# Query ISODate at specific date with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to make a query with mongoose that will show results based on the user typing but the problem is how I can make it when the user will start typing date for instance 2019-08 to appear all results on that date, if I change type of the property in mongoose from date to string it works but that's is not a good way to solve the problem, I tried different answers that were posted in STACKOVERFLOW but i didn't had success.

So my query right now is like this:

```
ForeignEmployee.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "grouplists",
          localField: "groupList",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "group"
        }
      },
      { $unwind: "$group" },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "companies",
          localField: "company",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "company"
        }
      },
      { $unwind: "$company" },
      {
        $match: {
          $or: [
            // { name: { $regex: findBy, $options: "i" } },
            // { surname: { $regex: findBy, $options: "i" } },
            // { username: { $regex: findBy, $options: "i" } },
            // { role: { $regex: findBy, $options: "i" } },
            // { zone: { $regex: findBy, $options: "i" } },
            {
              launchDate: {
                $lt: new Date(findBy)
              }
            }
            // { position: { $regex: findBy, $options: "i" } },
            // { task: { $regex: findBy, $options: "i" } },
            // { "group.generatedName": { $regex: findBy, $options: "i" } },
            // { "group.date": { $regex: findBy, $options: "i" } },
            // { "group.time": { $regex: findBy, $options: "i" } },
            // { "company.company": { $regex: findBy, $options: "i" } }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          name: 1,
          surname: 1,
          username: 1,
          role: 1,
          zone: 1,
          launchDate: 1,
          position: 1,
          task: 1,
          company: 1,
          group: 1
        }
      }
    ])
```

Comment: what does your `findBy` looks like? Also, can you show us your schema?

Comment: const { findBy } = req.body;

findBy is parameter that i receive from FrontEnd usually it comes string